# Задача по Pandas. Сложная фильтрация

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Подскажите, прохожу обучение, не могу перешагнуть задание.

Отфильтруйте строки таким образом, чтобы оставить только те транзакции, у которых в соответствующий относительный день tr_day количество уникальных MCC кодов при транзакциях было больше 75.
Пробовал играться с группировками и с уникалmными, нашел метод unique, но не знаю как решить с ним задачу.

```
len(pd.unique(brx['mcc_code'])) > 75
```

Вот фрагмент данных, строк около миллиона.

```
        mcc_code  tr_type     amount  gender tr_day
946518      6010     7070   11229.58     0.0    439
902107      6010     7070  539019.79     0.0     19
826694      6010     7070    2762.48     1.0     79
799043      4511     6100  103087.53     0.0     52
944055      6010     7070    2021.32     0.0    231
974045      6010     7030   21422.22     1.0    426
930420      6010     7070   28625.99     1.0    414
864425      6010     7070    2515.43     1.0    278
875639      6010     7070    4985.93     1.0    347
803346      6010     7070    6221.19     1.0     18
927200      6010     7070    9107.19     1.0    258
943893      6010     7070     191.58     NaN    124
954317      6010     7030  224591.58     NaN    342
869456      6010     7070    3436.25     1.0    312
534079      6011     7010   22459.16     NaN    438
984953      6010     7071   11645.07     1.0    338
903626      6010     7070  336887.37     1.0    434
814477      6010     7070   44918.32     NaN    404
984236      6010     7071   11858.44     NaN    284
540267      6011     7010  673774.73     0.0    239>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

размер группы groupby(['tr_day', 'mcc_code']).size() даст количесто уникальных значений 'mcc_code' для каждого дня. чтобы отобрать те, где больше 75, при помощи transform можно положить их в колонку, и отобрать по её значению

```
df[df.groupby(['tr_day', 'mcc_code'])['mcc_code'].transform('size')>75]
```

во втором случае вместо 'mcc_code' можно подставить любую существующую колонку

Comment: вам вариант подошел, спасибо. буду разбираться.

Comment: я там немного написал, как работает

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, я не совсем ясно понял задачу, но, вероятно, вам нужно что-то вроде такого решения:

```
df[df.groupby('tr_day')['mcc_code'].transform('nunique')>75]
```

Comment: выводит только шапку без строк

Comment: @sstrawdog transform('nunique') -не колво повторов, а количество разных значений ? или я не прав?

Answer (score 0):

Всем доброго времени суток!
Хочу поделиться своим практическим решением данной задачи целиком.

*Task 4:
-Выделите из поля tr_datetime относительный день tr_day (первое число до точного времени).
-Отфильтруйте строки таким образом, чтобы оставить только те транзакции, у которых в соответствующий относительный день tr_day количество уникальных MCC кодов при транзакциях было больше 75 (можно воспользоваться функцией nunique())
-Сгруппируйте полученный отфильтрованный датафрейм по MCC коду и полу, после чего, пронализировав результат, выберите верные варианты ответов ниже:

1. gender == 0 - женщины, gender == 1 - мужчины
2. gender == 1 - женщины, gender == 0 - мужчины
3. Абсолютное значение медианы с типом "Флористика" (расходов/приходов) у мужчин выше той же медианы у женщин
4. Абсолютное значение медианы женских трат (расходов/приходов) на ценные бумаги выше мужских
5. Абсолютное значение медианы женских трат (расходов/приходов) в категории "Бары, коктейль-бары, дискотеки, ночные клубы и таверны — места продажи алкогольных напитков" ниже мужских
   Пояснения:
   -Для того, чтобы выделить всё, что стоит до первого пробела, можо использовать строковые методы для датафрейма - .str.split(), например. Либо же реализовывать логику выделения подстроки с помощью метода apply.
   -Понять, какой класс к какому типу транзакций (мужские/женские) относится можно, если поизучать типичные для мужчин/женщин категории и сравнить средние/медианы расходов и/или приходов в них.*

Дилетантским, конечно, способом, но давшим правильный ответ:)
(Я начал изучать Питон и решал эту задачу в рамках курса "Python для анализа данных", Сберуниверситет. На ней очень сильно споткнулся...)

`import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

pd.options.display.max_rows = 10`

#закачиваем данные из файлов (сами файлы не привожу, считаю, что они у вас есть)

`customers_gender_train = pd.read_csv("Python And Data Analysis/data/gender_train.csv", sep = ',')

tr_types = pd.read_csv("Python And Data Analysis/data/tr_types.csv",
sep = ';')

tr_mcc_codes = pd.read_csv("Python And Data Analysis/data/tr_mcc_codes.csv",
sep = ';')

transactions = pd.read_csv("Python And Data Analysis/data/transactions.csv",
sep = ',', nrows = 1000000)`

#осуществляем необходимые слияния таблиц (Task 0):

`t = pd.merge(transactions,tr_mcc_codes)

t1 = pd.merge(t,tr_types)

t2 = pd.merge(t1, customers_gender_train, how='left')

t2 #смотрим, что получилось`

#Собственно, решение:

#разбиваем дату-время на отдельные колонки (отделяя их в новую табличку):

`new_t2 = t2['tr_datetime'].str.split(' ',expand=True)

new_t2.columns=['tr_day','tr_time'] #даем колонкам нужные названия

new_t2['tr_day'] = pd.to_numeric(new_t2.tr_day) #делаем колонку tr_day числовой

t2 = pd.concat([t2,new_t2],axis=1) #сливаемся с основной таблицей

t2 #смотрим, что получилось`

#осуществляем необходимую фильтрацию:

`g2 = t2.groupby(['tr_day'])`
#здесь ТОЛЬКО группируем (разбиваем исходный фрейм на группы; с 'mcc_code' пока ничего не делаем! считать (ПРИМЕНЯТЬ ФУНКЦИЮ) будем потом!

`t22 = g2.filter(lambda x: x['mcc_code'].nunique() > 75)  #СОЛЬ ЗДЕСЬ!!! :)`
#ну а теперь фильтруем ИСХОДНЫЙ фрейм
t2 - ПРИМЕНЯЕМ ФУНКЦИЮ к каждой группе
#- Function to apply to each subframe. Should return True or False. (из pandas.pydata.org - DataFrameGroupBy.filter)

`t22 #смотрим, что получилось`

#изучаем вручную (в отдельной табличке) мужские и женские mcc_code:

`pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000
t222 = t22.copy()

t222.sort_values(by=['mcc_code','gender'], inplace=True)

t222["abs_amount"] = abs(t222.amount) #абс. значение суммы, т.е. не важно тратили или получали деньги

t222.groupby(['mcc_description','gender']).abs_amount.median()  `
#определение пола: 1-мужики (мото,горючее,спирт,дороги...)
#0-дамы (секонд, бакалея, ж.одежда...)

#находим ответы на вопросы 3-5:

`pd.options.display.max_rows = 10

t222[t222["mcc_description"].str.contains("Флористика")].groupby(['gender']).amount.median() #3`
gender
0.0   -12352.54
1.0   -19090.28
#ДА - 3) Абсолютное значение медианы с типом "Флористика" (расходов/приходов) у мужчин выше той же медианы у женщин

`t222[t222["mcc_description"].str.contains("Ценные бумаги")].groupby(['gender']).amount.median() #4`
gender
0.0    -6737.75
1.0   -11229.58
#НЕТ - 4) Абсолютное значение медианы женских трат (расходов/приходов) на ценные бумаги выше мужских (Ценные бумаги: брокеры/дилеры)

`t222[t222["mcc_description"].str.contains("коктейль-бары")].groupby(['gender']).amount.median() #5`
gender
0.0    -9387.93
1.0   -12667.86
#ДА - 5) Абсолютное значение медианы женских трат (расходов/приходов) в категории "Бары, коктейль-бары, дискотеки,
#ночные клубы и таверны — места продажи алкогольных напитков" ниже мужски